# Javascript Inequalities

Tags: javascript

So I'm making a Javascript program for "rock paper scissor lizard Spock" and I'm using `Math.random()`. I need to use `if/else/else if's`. Can somebody help me with the inequalities? I know what I currently have is not quite right:

```
   var userChoice = prompt("Do you choose Rock, Paper, Scissors, Lizard or Spock?");
var computerChoice = Math.random();
if (computerChoice > 0.20) {
    computerChoice = "rock";
} else if(computerChoice < 0.40 && >=0.20) {
    computerChoice = "paper";
} else if(computerChoice <0.60 && >=0.40 {
    computerChoice = "scissors";
}else if(computerChoice <0.80 && =>0.60 {
    computerChoice = "lizard";
}else {
    computerChoice = "Spock";
}
```

Comment: Hi Welcome to SO. In general you should to tell us the error, the error message, so as we can help quickly. How did you spot that your code is wrong ?

Answer (score 1):

You need both a left and a right operand in each of the conditionals. That is:

```
else if(computerChoice < 0.40 && computerChoice >=0.20) {
```

Answer (score 1):

I'm not familiair with the game, so I don't know what the winning order is. But this could help you. It's just assingning numbers to the words and compares the numbers.

I've made a [little fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/ezwyeyy2/1/)

```
var userChoice = prompt("Do you choose Rock, Paper, Scissors, Lizard or Spock?");

var test = {
    Rock: 0,
    Paper: 1,
    Scissors: 2,
    Lizard: 3,
    Spock: 4
};

userChoice = test[userChoice]; //a number from 0 - 4

var computerChoice = Math.floor(Math.random() * 5); //(gives number from 0 to 4)

if (userChoice == computerChoice) {
    alert('it\'s a tie');
} else if (userChoice > computerChoice) {
    alert('user wins');
} else {
    alert('computer wins');
}
```